# Rental income taxes

Tags: income-tax, rental-property

My parents found a home for sale in their area they wanted to buy for rental purposes, but couldn't qualify for the loan. So I took out a loan and purchased it.

They are now renting it out and have taken in rental income for 2023. This money goes into their account. They pay the mortgage in my name. But I claim the interest on my taxes since the form comes to my name as the borrower.

Do I need to claim the income and pay taxes on it or is it totally on them?

Comment: All tax questions require us to know the country.  Please include that information. Also is there a rental agreement or something in writing between you and your parents?

Comment: *Do I need to claim the income and pay taxes on it or is it totally on them?* Who has the *tenant* signed the lease  with? I don't know what country you're at, but if it is the US - you can't claim mortgage interest deduction if you didn't actually pay that interest.

Comment: There is an awful lot of financial commingling going on here.  I would strongly suggest that you and your parents sit down with a tax advisor.  This is not something I’d rely on random internet people for.

Answer (score 3):

Answering from a United States point of view. I am also assuming that there isn't a lawyer draft agreement that would change the financial picture.

> They are now renting it out and have taken in rental income for 2023.
> This money goes into their account. They pay the mortgage in my name.
> But I claim the interest on my taxes since the form comes to my name
> as the borrower.

You own the house. You have the mortgage. You are renting the house to your parents. Their rent payment is the amount of check they are sending to your bank. I am assuming that that check is covering principal and interest plus the escrow to cover taxes and insurance.

From the point of view of the IRS you have rental income of that check, and you can count as expenses the interest, taxes, and insurance. That means the principal paid each month isn't an amount you can deduct. You could have other expenses if there is a HOA or condo fee, or if you paid for a repair.

In addition you should take into account the depreciation of the home. There is a whole process related to figuring the value that can be depreciated. You want to do this because it will significantly reduce the income tax on the rental income. When it is time to sell the IRS will make you figure the profit based on how much you should have depreciated the value, so it makes sense to do this.

Depending on the numbers involved you may owe taxes on the income.

Now your parents have rental income, and rental expense. They will have to document this in order to claim the expense or they will have to count all of the income as taxable. In documenting their expense they will likely have to include your information, so expect that the federal and state government will be looking for the income on your tax forms.

A complication you face is did the mortgage company know about this arrangement? Does the insurance company? You don't want an issue to crop up in the future.

Comment: That's definitely one way to look at it, another might be: you (the OP) are giving a gift to your parents which is the difference between what your house costs *to you* and what they pay *on your behalf*. Depending on the amounts, one may be a better argument than the other, but absent any paperwork it can go either way and the IRS may claim whatever is best *for them* (which would be the gift route, I'd guess).